# Unicorn vs single threaded Puma

Tags: multithreading, heroku, unicorn, puma

Heroku has been advocating Puma over Unicorn for some time now. Primarily because of Puma's better handling of slow clients.

Why is Puma better at this? Is it simply because it's multithreaded and can handle more concurrent connections or is there more to it (e.g. an event driven model like Node)?

Put another way, will Puma be just as bad as Unicorn when handling slow clients if you were to set its max thread count to 1?

Thanks,
Sebastian :)